# REST URL structure advice

Tags: http, url, rest

I'm trying to finalise on a restful url structure for the wishlist section of a site I'm working on. It's a pretty simple model, a user can have many wishlists and each wishlist can contain many products.

Currently I have the obvious CRUD URLs to manipulate the wishlist itself :

```
GET account/wishlists.json
GET account/wishlists/{id}.json
POST account/wishlists.json?name=My%20Wishlist
POST account/wishlists/{id}.json?name=My%20New%20Name
DELETE account/wishlists/{id}.json
```

However, I don't think I know how to structure the URLs that would add/remove a product to a wishlist :(

Here are my current choices :

**1)** Have the product to add as part of the URL and use the HTTP verb to define my action

```
POST account/wishlist/{id}/product/{product_id}.json
DELETE account/wishlist/{id}/product/{product_id}.json
```

or

**2**) Have the action as part of the URL and the product id as part of the payload

```
POST account/wishlist/{id}/add.json?product_id={product_id}
POST account/wishlist/{id}/remove.json?product_id={product_id}
```

(1) is clean and, as far as I can tell it's pretty RESTful but doesn't allow things like adding multiple products easily etc.

I'm also a bit concerned about using the DELETE verb - I'm not deleting the product or the wishlist, I'm just removing one from the other.

(2) is more explicit but veers away from REST - I wouldn't be just referring to the resource in the url, I would be referring to an operation on that resource :(

Any advice on which of the above would be more correct would be very helpful! (If there's a third option that's better than mine, feel free to correct me!)

Comment: Too lazy for a full blown answer, but just to be clear, **option two can in no way be considered REST** as you have an action in the URI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(1) is the only valid approach for REST, using HTTP verbs for actions.

(2) encodes method names into the URI which is more like RPC and of course not RESTful.

Concerning your shortcomings about the first approach:

- The `DELETE` verb is fine, because your resource is the item inside in the wishlist, not the item itself.
- You can support batch requests. For instance, you might want to allow to `POST` a list of items to a wishlist resource resulting in mutliple adds.

PS: Prefer HTTP content negotiation (Accept and Content-Type headers) over representation formats encoded in the URI.

Comment: Regarding content negotiation etc, I'm anticipating allowing whatever the user wants to send, either headers or url extensions; it's just easiest to write _.json_ in my examples ;)

Comment: Okay, just stumbled on your example and wanted to mention it :-)

Comment: @deanWombourne @PartlyCloudy I think `.format` has it's rights in explicitly asking for return in a specific format, since in case of acceptance headers the server decides which format to send ultimately. However, if no JSON-response is available (in your example) or the user asks for a format not providable (.xml when you have only json) you MUST return a 404 Not Found header instead of providing an alternative represantion.

Comment: @SamuelHerzog nothing forces the the server to pay attention to the format in the URI. I'd argue the only time it makes sense for formats to be in the URI is when humans are entering the URI into a web browser, as it's (currently) too tedious to manually set headers. Content negotiation via headers should be the default. The server can still return an appropriate response if such a format cannot be handled.

Comment: @thecoshman when building an API your main interest should be your user/consumer - that's why we need REST in the first place. I argue that if you give the consumer the possibility of asking for an explicit format (allowing file-system-like-URIs) you need to handle content properly: If the consumer asks for an XML file you need to serve XML or tell the user it isn't available. If your client is able to content-negotiate he has the means to react to changes in file format. If you expose an API with "file-endings" you can't rely on that anymore and need to react with a 404 status code.

Comment: @SamuelHerzog I was getting more at the fact that nothing *forces* the server to respond with file format that was requested. I'd also say that in the end, there's no major difference between a client using a 'file extension' to denote request format and offering a single format in the `Accept` header. However the server wants to respond, it should be the same for both. And yes, 404 is probably the best way to respond to that, but not a good way imo... need some way to show what formats can requested by the client.

Comment: @thecoshman nothing forces the server, but you shouldn't respond to *.jpg with a worm (remember that? ;-) ) - I argue there is a distinct difference, as the negotiation process is well-defined. Whereas calling with a "file-ending" is out of the rest-realm and should be treated accordingly. error handling is a whole different matter and should in this case include 1) a meaningful error-message in the response body and 2) An accept header with the available formats. Additionally: failed content negotation should be answered with 406, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html

Comment: @SamuelHerzog yes, well obviously what you *can* do is not what you *should* do. I don't think calling for a particular format really makes a difference, both a viable HTTP approaches, and thus viable REST. Either way the server should 'politely' tell the client it can't have that format. The advantage with `Accept` header is that a client can accept multiple formats and the server can choose a prefered format, with extensions you only get one.

Answer (score 3):

I think your first option is more in line with the REST philosophy. If you want to manipulate multiple products, you could pass the ids as a list in the body, instead of using a query parameter.

As for the delete part, given that you are deleting a subresource of wishlist, I think the intention is clear (i.e. remove the connection from the wishlist to the product). If you wanted to globally remove a product, the URL should be something like

```
DELETE /products/{id}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by other responses, the first option is clearly the RESTful approach.  The approach to deleting products from the wishlist looks fine - after all you would be doing a `DELETE` on `product/{product_id}` to remove the product itself.

For adding products, you might wish to consider a `POST` to `account/wishlist/{id}/product/` the body of which could contain a list of product IDs.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a nice article](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) on how to think about REST URLs